# object method vs prototype method

Tags: javascript

```
   var MyClass = function() {};    

   MyClass.method = function (name, age) { 
        return "My name is " + name + " and I'm " + age + " years old";          
    }

    MyClass.prototype.method = function (name, age) { 
        return "My name is " + name + " and I'm " + age + " years old";   
    }

    console.log(MyClass.method('David','30'));

    var instance = new MyClass();      

    console.log(instance.method('john', '23'));
```

In above code snippet, both methods are doing same thing. In most cases both can be used interchangeably. Which one would you chose and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype method is shared between all instances, which makes the object lighter.

Comment: Is there any reason to use non prototype method then?

Comment: If you don't want to have specific method per instance, and if you declare objects using `new`, then there is no reason.

Comment: Always use constructor/prototype where possible, it's more efficient. Is it true?

Comment: No, just using a constructor isn't more efficient than building an object with `{}`. It starts to be more efficient when you have to share functions between instances.

Answer (score 0):

It's just like a static member vs instance member in C# or Java. The non-prototype will not have access to the parameters within an object for example.

You wouldn't be able to do this within `MyClass.method` for example because you're calling it on MyClass, not an **instance of** MyClass. [(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nfjyV/)

```
var MyClass = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};

MyClass.prototype.method = function () { 
    return "My name is " + this.name + " and I'm " + this.age + " years old";   
}

var instance = new MyClass('David', 10);
console.log(instance.method());
```